# C# code want perfect output and justification

Tags: c#-3.0

```
 class Base
    {
        public virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base method");
        }
    }
    class Derived : Base
    {
        public override void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived method");
        }
    }
    class MyClient
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            Base b1 = new Derived();
            b1.Method(); // Displays 'Base Method' 
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

what should be the output?

how it come? please explain

Comment: Did you ever try to compile & run ?

Answer (score 1):

The output should be, and *is*, `Derived Method."  When you override a method in a derived class, you are changing the implementation of that method for any instance of the class.

So, even though you are referencing `b1` as a `Base`, the runtime knows it is in fact an instance of `Derived` and will use the latter's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It will display the "Derived Method" . now come to the code , what exactly you are doing in `Class Myclient` .See you are creating a object of `B` class with `Derived` class constructor.so run time will go through `derived` class ,and cretae an instance of `derived` class .and result will be the "Derived method"